# Firebase response says success, but no notification on device

Tags: c#, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I used the following code to send a push notification from my server to an Android device:

```
public string SendNotification(string deviceId, string message)
{
    string GoogleAppID = "anonymized";
    var SENDER_ID = "anonymized";
    var value = message;
    WebRequest tRequest;
    tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    tRequest.Method = "post";
    tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));

    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

    string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + deviceId + "";
    Console.WriteLine(postData);
    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

    dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();


    tReader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    tResponse.Close();
    return sResponseFromServer;
}
```

I called the function like that:

```
string str = new AndroidGCMPushNotification().SendNotification(registration.DeviceToken, "Hello!");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

The feedback of firebase is the following:

```
id=0:1491212883976938%e6b70caa66d6cf16
```

The 0 says, the push notification was created successfully. But I don't receive the message on my Android device. I can exclude a networking problem.

On my client side, I created this class:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
    }
}
```

Plus, I added the AndroidManifest.xml with the following:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

What could be my problem?

Comment: make sure the app that receive the notification is in background

Comment: I tried that and there was no difference

Comment: I just noticed that changing the SENDER_ID variable to a random string does not affect the feedback.

Comment: what value did you use in SENDER_ID

Comment: @Badr I used "29373768066" - it is the ID I took from my firebase console.

Comment: ok what about fire base token of the receiver app

Comment: @Badr I am able to send test notifications to this device via firebase console, so the token should be ok.

Comment: @Badr I came a bit further. When I send a notification from my program, the app crashes. At least, there is something happening

Comment: can you post the exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139766/discussion-between-localhorst27-and-badr).

Comment: Hi. Do post the Client side code. My guess here is that you're code is only handling `notification` messages, but not `data` messages.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: Hi, did you solved that issue? Im in that trouble too.